# Syntax to remove the single coutes in temp table column in db2

Tags: db2, websphere, db2-400

EX:
table employee column below
EmpID
'10001'

expected result:

EmpID
10001

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select 
  empid
, translate (empid, '', '''') as empid_new
from (values '''1001''') employee (empid)
```

The result is:

| EMPID | EMPID_NEW |
| --- | --- |
| '1001' | 1001 |

Comment: Blow query works for me :-                                                                                                     
              select replace(yourfield,'''','') from yourtable

Comment: There is a number of ways to do it. For example, `trim ('''' from empid)` to remove just leading and trailing single quote symbols, but not intermediate ones if they exist.